# Convert structured numpy array (containing sub-arrays) to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

### Problem

As an example, consider the following structured numpy array (containing sub-arrays):

```
data = [
    (1, (5., 3., 7.), 6),
    (2, (2., 1., 3.), 9),
    (3, (3., 8., 4.), 3),
    (4, (1., 7., 4.), 2),
]
dtype = [('A', '<i8'), ('B', '<f8', (3,)), ('C', '<i8')]
arr = np.array(data, dtype=dtype)
```

I would like to convert this array `arr` into a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
   A  B_1  B_2  B_3  C
0  1  5.0  3.0  7.0  6
1  2  2.0  1.0  3.0  9
2  3  3.0  8.0  4.0  3
3  4  1.0  7.0  4.0  2
```

### Tried thus far

I've tried to use pandas' method [`from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) to perform the conversion:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(arr)
```

but this throws the error `Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional`.

### Question

What would be a good way to perform such a conversion to pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be flatten with two `pd.DataFrame` call

```
df=pd.DataFrame(arr.tolist())
df=df.join(pd.DataFrame(df[1].tolist()).add_prefix('B'))
Out[404]: 
   0                1  2   B0   B1   B2
0  1  [5.0, 3.0, 7.0]  6  5.0  3.0  7.0
1  2  [2.0, 1.0, 3.0]  9  2.0  1.0  3.0
2  3  [3.0, 8.0, 4.0]  3  3.0  8.0  4.0
3  4  [1.0, 7.0, 4.0]  2  1.0  7.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do (assuming you know, that column `B` is the one to be expanded, you can iterate over `dtype` if you need to automate it further- to get the ones of compound type)

```py
df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(map(lambda x: list(x), arr), columns=arr.dtype.names)
df2=pd.DataFrame(df["B"].tolist())
df2.columns=map(lambda x: f"B_{x+1}", df2.columns)

df=pd.concat([df, df2], sort=False, axis=1).drop(columns="B")
```

Outputs:

```py
   A  C  B_1  B_2  B_3
0  1  6  5.0  3.0  7.0
1  2  9  2.0  1.0  3.0
2  3  3  3.0  8.0  4.0
3  4  2  1.0  7.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [56]: data = [ 
    ...:     (1, (5., 3., 7.), 6), 
    ...:     (2, (2., 1., 3.), 9), 
    ...:     (3, (3., 8., 4.), 3), 
    ...:     (4, (1., 7., 4.), 2), 
    ...: ] 
    ...: dtype = [('A', '<i8'), ('B', '<f8', (3,)), ('C', '<i8')] 
    ...: arr = np.array(data, dtype=dtype)                                                     
In [57]: arr                                                                                   
Out[57]: 
array([(1, [5., 3., 7.], 6), (2, [2., 1., 3.], 9), (3, [3., 8., 4.], 3),
       (4, [1., 7., 4.], 2)],
      dtype=[('A', '<i8'), ('B', '<f8', (3,)), ('C', '<i8')])
```

Looks like the newish `structure_to_unstructured` can handle this dtype:

```
In [59]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf                                                   
In [60]: rf.structured_to_unstructured(arr)                                                    
Out[60]: 
array([[1., 5., 3., 7., 6.],
       [2., 2., 1., 3., 9.],
       [3., 3., 8., 4., 3.],
       [4., 1., 7., 4., 2.]])
```

then make the dataframe in the usual way.

```
In [63]: pd.DataFrame(_60, columns=['A','B1','B2','B3','C'])                                   
Out[63]: 
     A   B1   B2   B3    C
0  1.0  5.0  3.0  7.0  6.0
1  2.0  2.0  1.0  3.0  9.0
2  3.0  3.0  8.0  4.0  3.0
3  4.0  1.0  7.0  4.0  2.0
```

and add in the column dtypes

```
In [74]: df = pd.DataFrame(_60, columns=['A','B1','B2','B3','C'])                              
In [75]: df['A']=df['A'].astype(int)                                                           
In [76]: df['C']=df['C'].astype(int)                                                           
In [77]: df                                                                                    
Out[77]: 
   A   B1   B2   B3  C
0  1  5.0  3.0  7.0  6
1  2  2.0  1.0  3.0  9
2  3  3.0  8.0  4.0  3
3  4  1.0  7.0  4.0  2
```